# ChatGPT + Telegram bot - Responses are not related to the prompt

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openai-api

I've been messing around with a Telegram bot that generates an answer based on a prompt given by the user. I got it all working, but the responses given are very weird and not related to the prompt. For example, I ask;

/text hello, how are you?

It responds with:

?”

“I’m good. How are you?”

“I’m good.”

“How are you?”

“I’m good.”

“How are you?”

“I’m good.”

Has anyone had this before? It's really weird and I think I'm doing something wrong. Code below:

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
import re
import openai

# Initialize the Telegram Bot
bot = telegram.Bot(token='hidden')

# Initialize the OpenAI API
openai.api_key = "hidden"

# Define the command handler
def text_handler(update, context):
    # Get the input text from the user
    input_text = update.message.text

    # Extract the prompt from the input text
    prompt = re.sub('/text', '', input_text).strip()

    # Generate response using OpenAI
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine="davinci",
        prompt=prompt,
        max_tokens=100,
        n=1,
        stop=None,
        temperature=0.4,
    )

    # Get the generated text from the response
    generated_text = response.choices[0].text.strip()

    # Send the generated text back to the user
    update.message.reply_text(generated_text)

# Create an Updater object and attach the command handler to it
updater = Updater(token='hidden', use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('text', text_handler))

# Start the bot
updater.start_polling()
```

I've tried different engines and changing the parameters but nothing seemed to change the answers.

Comment: Your title refers to ChatGPT but code uses text completion endpoint (`openai.Completion.create`). If you'd like to use Chat Completion endpoint, use `openai.ChatCompletion.create` -- https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what kind of output you were expecting, I will generalize.

If you receive very short replies or not as "creative" as you'd like, turn up the temperature. Also beware of `max_tokens` parameter, as longer replies require more tokens.

Read about `presence_penalty` and `frequency_penalty` to modify the way the model responds in create completion documentation section [here](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create)

Comment: I was expecting answers like the ChatGPT3 web is giving me. I've also tried other bots (which run on davinci) and asked the same question, their response is what I was expecting too:

As an AI language model, I don't have feelings like humans do. However, I'm functioning normally and ready to assist you with any questions or tasks you might have. How can I assist you today?

Comment: Read about `presence_penalty`and `frequency_penalty` to modify the way the model responds in create completion documentation section https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create